# jsp in nullpointer error netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans

test.jsp

```
try {

    Integer id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    String name=request.getParameter("name"); 

    // Class.forName("jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    Connection cn;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    //cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:JAY");
    cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://J//DB//database.accdb");
    st=cn.createStatement();
    String s="Select * from emp where EMP_ID="+id+" or EMP_NAME='"+name+"'";
    rs=st.executeQuery(s);

    if((id.equals("") || id.equals("null")) && (name.equals("") || name.equals("null"))) {
        out.print("Enter the username or password");
    }

    // if(id.equals(""))
    if("".equals(id)) {
        out.print("Enter the username or password");
    }
    else if(id.equals("null")) {
        out.print("Enter the username or password");
    }
    else if(name.equals("")) {
        out.print("Enter the username or password");
    }
    else if(name.equals("null")) {
        out.print("Enter the username or password");
    }

    else {
        if(rs.next()) {   
            Integer w=rs.getInt("EMP_ID");
            String z=rs.getString("EMP_NAME");
            HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
            sess.setAttribute("user", name);
            if((id.equals(w)) && (name.equals(z))) {
                out.println("<center><h1>ID is: " + id + "</h1>");
                out.println("<center><h1>Welcome: " + name + "</h1>");
                response.sendRedirect("jsp1.jsp");
            } 
            else {
                out.println("You enter wrong username or password");
            }        
        } 
        else {
            out.println("You enter wrong username or password");
        } 
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
}
```

when i fill correct detail to login and get session id 
when i not fill in id text box and name fill bt i m getting this error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

but i already check null condition
why it not execute that code

and same case if u pass the value in string in id textbox
that time this error got

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "jay"

how to handle string value pass?

Answer (score 0):

You get java.lang.NumberFormatException when you try to parse an empty String to int. Your null / empty String check is after your parseInt() method.

You should make null check before you try to parseInt().

Following is a suggestion for your current code. Please note that there are better ways to implement your use case. I suggest that you improve yourself in language basics, debugging etc. first (before going into web development)

```
try {
    String idParam=request.getParameter("id"); 
    String name=request.getParameter("name"); 
    int id = 0;

    if(idParam == null || idParam.trim() =="" || name == null || name.trim() == ""){
          out.print('Enter username or ...');
    }else {
        try{
            id = Integer.parseInt(idParam);

        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            out.print("Please enter number for id");
        }

        // Class.forName("jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        Connection cn;
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;
        //cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:JAY");
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D://J//DB//database.accdb");
        st=cn.createStatement();
        String s="Select * from emp where EMP_ID="+id+" or EMP_NAME='"+name+"'";
        rs=st.executeQuery(s);

        if(rs.next()) {   
            Integer w=rs.getInt("EMP_ID");
            String z=rs.getString("EMP_NAME");
            HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
            sess.setAttribute("user", name);

            if((id.equals(w)) && (name.equals(z))) {
                out.println("<center><h1>ID is: " + id + "</h1>");
                out.println("<center><h1>Welcome: " + name + "</h1>");
                response.sendRedirect("jsp1.jsp");
            } 
            else {
                out.println("You enter wrong username or password");
            }      

    }    
}
catch(Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: first thanx for reply .   can u show me how to check bcz when i use in integer value it check bt when i pass to null or string value it getting same error .hw can i handle it.

Comment: I did not understand what you are asking in your comment

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about data conversion in java. For example, just run these code snippets outside of any web application - no need to have a complicated environment to learn about conversion. Run it in a debugger to understand how it works. Insert try/catch for any exception thrown. Think about why these exceptions might be thrown and what change you can do against them. Then find conversion libraries or patterns and apply these:

```
Integer result = Integer.parseInt("1");
result = Integer.parseInt("Text");
result = Integer.parseInt(null);

String value = "";
if(value.equals("")) System.out.println("empty String 1");
value = null;
if(value.equals("")) System.out.println("empty String 2");
if(value.equals("null")) System.out.println("null String 1");
if(value.equals(null)) System.out.println("null String 2");
```

Further more - the way you encode your SQL statements with input data opens you up to SQL-injection attacks. Read/Learn about this topic at [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: thanx for reply bro.    can show me hw to sloved this problem plz